# Unable to start activity in my MainActivity

Tags: android, exception

I shall try my best to post the relevant code and explain clearly... I'm following a tutorial on Android; it was a ListView Application which I am now converting to fragments. It told me to change one of my classes from `extends ListActivity` to `extends Activity`. In doing so, two of my calls particular to ListActivity needed changing. I thought I changed them properly, but I am getting these errors (just the top of the list):

```
W/dalvikvm(4486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40209760)
E/AndroidRuntime(4486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(4486): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.MainActivity}:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
```

My main activity code, the part I believe relevant, is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_fragment);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_fragment);
    lv.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.tut_titles, R.layout.activity_main));
    final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tut_links);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick......

        }
    });
}
```

The lv variable is new, and the two calls made with it used to be ListActivity specific. My list_fragment is merely this so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.example.testing.UrlFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment">
</fragment>
```

Phew! I think that's all that's needed, but if I knew for certain, I could probably fix this myself. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in following line.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_fragment);
```

From R file you are referencing fragment but you are going to cast it to ListView that is your problem.you can simply solve it as follows.

1) create a class extending Fragment.

```
public static class YourFragmentClass extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

2) In your activity class.

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = new YourFragmentClass ();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_fragmentr, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

3) for more [check this out](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Of course! I should have spotted that... But it has to be a fragment; I can't change it to a listview. Any ideas on how I can make that work?

Comment: ok AmberWolfe i have edited the answer hope it will help you.